# navbar click is under the item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, navbar

I'm sure it is a simple fix, but I cannot find my mistake!
On my `navbar`, when I'm about to click any item, once I hover, it does nothing, but if I put my mouse below the item, it shows the hover and it is clickable.

**When mouse over the item,** nothing happens.

[image]

**When mouse below the item,** the hover happens and it is clickable

[image]

How can I correct it?

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

section {
    height: calc(90% - 50px);
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li.active a {
    background-color: #6dafad;
    /* cor de fundo do que está seleccionado */
    color: #fff;
    /* cor do texto do que está seleccionado */
    border-radius: 2rem;
    /* adiciona as arestas redondas */
    margin: 0 0.25em;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    /* altera a cor de texto do cabeçalho */
    color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: #d4e1e3;
    /* altera a cor de texto do cabeçalho quando se passa com o rato por cima */
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,
/* altera a cor de fundo do elemento activo quando se passa por cima */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #d4e1e3;
    background-color: #6dafad;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,
/* altera a cor de fundo do elemento activo quando se abre o dropdown */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
    color: #d4e1e3;
    background-color: #6dafad;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    /* adiciona as arestas redondas */
    margin: 0 0.25em;
}

.affix {
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: padding 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: padding 0.2s linear;
    transition: padding 0.2s linear;
}

.affix-top {
    padding-top: 15px;
    /* altura entre texto e topo cabeçalho */
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    /* altura entre texto e base cabeçalho */
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: padding 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: padding 0.5s linear;
    transition: padding 0.5s linear;
}

.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    /* se não estiver, parte do logo - zona branca - fica comida -> esquerda */
    max-height: 50px;
    /* altura maxima do logotipo */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">

<head>
    <title>Bebés e Crianças</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/ihover.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <body>

        <div id="wrap">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-light navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #97CACA; color: #fff; border-color: transparent;"
                data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                            aria-controls="navbar">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand navbar-fixed-top" href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive logo" width="300" height="300" src="https://preview.ibb.co/fSRAjS/logo.png"
                                alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li>
                                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="sobre-nos.html">Sobre Nós</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Serviços
                                    <b class="caret active"></b>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li class="active">
                                        <a href="criancas.html">Bebés e Crianças</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="adultos.html">Adultos e Séniores</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="empresas.html">Empresas</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="jobs.html">Venha trabalhar conosco!</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="contactos.html">Contactos</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

**When mouse over the item**

[image]

Comment: If you want to use the code editor of stackoverflow correctly you should mind to reduce your html code. For instance remove the html, head and body tag.

Comment: Could you consider to mark your question as solved? Otherwise provide further information to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do not mix `navbar-brand` and `navbar-fixed-top`. The second class is reserved for the navbar wrapper.
2. Adjust the `.navbar-brand` to be positioned fixed.

With these two little fixes the overlaying logo will set the navigation bar free.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

section {
  height: calc(90% - 50px);
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li.active a {
  background-color: #6dafad;
  /* cor de fundo do que está seleccionado */
  color: #fff;
  /* cor do texto do que está seleccionado */
  border-radius: 2rem;
  /* adiciona as arestas redondas */
  margin: 0 0.25em;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  /* altera a cor de texto do cabeçalho */
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #d4e1e3;
  /* altera a cor de texto do cabeçalho quando se passa com o rato por cima */
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,

/* altera a cor de fundo do elemento activo quando se passa por cima */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #d4e1e3;
  background-color: #6dafad;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,

/* altera a cor de fundo do elemento activo quando se abre o dropdown */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  color: #d4e1e3;
  background-color: #6dafad;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  /* adiciona as arestas redondas */
  margin: 0 0.25em;
}

.affix {
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: padding 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: padding 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: padding 0.2s linear;
  transition: padding 0.2s linear;
}

.affix-top {
  padding-top: 15px;
  /* altura entre texto e topo cabeçalho */
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  /* altura entre texto e base cabeçalho */
  -webkit-transition: padding 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: padding 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: padding 0.5s linear;
  transition: padding 0.5s linear;
}
/* Adjusting navbar-brand class for fixed position*/
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  //padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  //padding-left: 5px;
  /* se não estiver, parte do logo - zona branca - fica comida -> esquerda */
  max-height: 50px;
  /* altura maxima do logotipo */
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="styles/ihover.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrap">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-light navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #97CACA; color: #fff; border-color: transparent;" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- Removed "navbar-fixed-top"; this class is reserved for the the whole navbar -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img class="img-responsive logo" width="300" height="300" src="https://preview.ibb.co/fSRAjS/logo.png" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="sobre-nos.html">Sobre Nós</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Serviços
                                        <b class="caret active"></b>
                                    </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li class="active">
                <a href="criancas.html">Bebés e Crianças</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="adultos.html">Adultos e Séniores</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="empresas.html">Empresas</a>
              </li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <a href="jobs.html">Venha trabalhar conosco!</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="contactos.html">Contactos</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To override the default styling by bootstrap I specified the `.navbar-brand` a little bit. So you do not have to worry about the defaults neither `!important`.

If your CSS looks like this, you've got a [specificity](https://specificity.keegan.st/) of 10 points:

```
.navbar-brand { ... }
```

If your CSS looks like this, you've got a [specificity](https://specificity.keegan.st/) of 30 points:

```
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-brand { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the navbar-brand. Its taking entire space on navbar. And why fixed top on navbar-brand.

Comment: You've identified the problem, but did not propose any solution.

Comment: the solution is give custom css for navbar-brand display: table; and remove navbar-fixed-top class from class navbar-brand

Comment: but the navbar-brand is to fix the brand at the left top of the screen. It was the only way I could find to fix it there.

Comment: why u need to fix navbar-brand, if you fix whole nav then it will be fixed. I actually never tried to use that fixed in my navbar-brand. May be your goal might be different.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of your logo. you need to add `class` in `a` tag of `logo`. here i have added `site-logo` class

```
<a class="navbar-brand navbar-fixed-top site-logo" href="#">
   <img class="img-responsive logo" width="300" height="300" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x50" alt="">
</a>
```

and add some lines of `css`

```
a.navbar-brand.navbar-fixed-top.site-logo {
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
}
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3akxLed5/2/)

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. 
There is no obligation to do this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `z-index` or the width property of your element with the classes `navbar-brand.navbar-fixed-top` as it currently sets on top of your navigation in the stacking order:

```
.navbar-brand.navbar-fixed-top {
      ...
      z-index: -1; /*Sets the element be positioned at the back of it's stacking context*/
      ...
}
```

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

section {
    height: calc(90% - 50px);
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li.active a {
    background-color: #6dafad;
    /* cor de fundo do que está seleccionado */
    color: #fff;
    /* cor do texto do que está seleccionado */
    border-radius: 2rem;
    /* adiciona as arestas redondas */
    margin: 0 0.25em;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    /* altera a cor de texto do cabeçalho */
    color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: #d4e1e3;
    /* altera a cor de texto do cabeçalho quando se passa com o rato por cima */
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,
/* altera a cor de fundo do elemento activo quando se passa por cima */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #d4e1e3;
    background-color: #6dafad;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,
/* altera a cor de fundo do elemento activo quando se abre o dropdown */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
    color: #d4e1e3;
    background-color: #6dafad;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    /* adiciona as arestas redondas */
    margin: 0 0.25em;
}

.affix {
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: padding 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: padding 0.2s linear;
    transition: padding 0.2s linear;
}

.affix-top {
    padding-top: 15px;
    /* altura entre texto e topo cabeçalho */
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    /* altura entre texto e base cabeçalho */
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: padding 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: padding 0.5s linear;
    transition: padding 0.5s linear;
}

.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    /* se não estiver, parte do logo - zona branca - fica comida -> esquerda */
    max-height: 50px;
    /* altura maxima do logotipo */
}

.navbar-brand.navbar-fixed-top {
z-index: -1; /*Sets element to be positioned at the back of it's stacking context*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">

<head>
    <title>Bebés e Crianças</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/ihover.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <body>

        <div id="wrap">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-light navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #97CACA; color: #fff; border-color: transparent;"
                data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                            aria-controls="navbar">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand navbar-fixed-top" href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive logo" width="300" height="300" src="https://preview.ibb.co/fSRAjS/logo.png"
                                alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li>
                                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="sobre-nos.html">Sobre Nós</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Serviços
                                    <b class="caret active"></b>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li class="active">
                                        <a href="criancas.html">Bebés e Crianças</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="adultos.html">Adultos e Séniores</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="empresas.html">Empresas</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="jobs.html">Venha trabalhar conosco!</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="contactos.html">Contactos</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Here is some information about the [z-index property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index) and [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)